# Codeigniter - input php automatically change % to + after submiting

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, input

I don't why this is happening.
I'm using mysql as database and the type data for this field is text.

I use textarea as the input container with POST method and this is the value.

login.imagesilo.com/EFormHost.aspx?PublicAccess=iTkJKhXDqXSbRZJadRifdGkxByxzVtSJp9E0RzhYdWeUuzUhUTW8YDzqnDHu2Ycu3%2b9JO%2fEfSE7Jdms6YtTrYptLnWjHiX7YNsZ0%2bTZzqWmhsaPdGWtpLd8dZLLC4qqx

after submitting and use echo to show the value I've inputed, the value changed to

login.imagesilo.com/EFormHost.aspx?PublicAccess=iTkJKhXDqXSbRZJadRifdGkxByxzVtSJp9E0RzhYdWeUuzUhUTW8YDzqnDHu2Ycu3+9JO/EfSE7Jdms6YtTrYptLnWjHiX7YNsZ0+TZzqWmhsaPdGWtpLd8dZLLC4qqx

this is very frustating. help me masters.

Comment: From what  I can see both the values look the same?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and it's not clear what are you trying to accomplish, please edit your question for everyone can get a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: sorry , I've edited the questions . thank you

Comment: It didn't change `%` to `+`, but `%2b` to `+` (and `%2f` to `/`) - did you do a [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode) somewhere?

Comment: I dont use the urldecode() , I input the first link then after I submit the form it change to the 2nd link . dont do anything. just use $post_data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); then echo the posted link

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
$data['link'] = $post_data['link'];
```

I dunno why, it changed the link value if I used above code
but stays the same using below code.

```
$data['link'] = $this->input->post('link');
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: The second argument (`true` in your first line of code) is whether to enable `XSS filtering` in codeignitor. Apparantly this also messes up the url-encoding. Another option was to set this one to `false` - that's also why your second solution is working, it's disabled by default in your installation/config.